# How can I upload file using vuex store on the vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

If I using ajax in vue component like this :

It works. I successfully get the file

But here I want to using vuex store

My pattern of vuex store like this :

I change my vue component like this :

```js
<template>
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        export default {
            methods: {
                submitForm() {
                    ...
                    formData.append('file', files)
                    this.updateProfile({formData, reload: true})
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

In the component vue, it will call updateProfile method in modules user

The modules user like this :

```
import { set } from 'vue'
import users from '../../api/users'
import * as types from '../mutation-types'
// initial state
const state = {
    addStatus:null
}
// getters
const getters = {
    updateProfileStatus: state =>  state.addStatus,
}
// actions
const actions = {
    updateProfile ({ dispatch,commit,state },{user,reload})
    {
        users.updateProfile(user,
            response => {
                commit(types.UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS)
            },
            errors => {
                commit(types.UPDATE_PROFILE_FAILURE)
            }
        )
    }
}
// mutations
const mutations = {
    [types.UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS] (state){
        state.addStatus = 'success'
    },
    [types.UPDATE_PROFILE_FAILURE] (state){
        state.addStatus = 'failure'
    }
}
export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

From the modules user, it will call updateProfile method in api users

The api users like this :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

```js
export default {

  updateProfile(user, cb, ecb = null) {
    axios.post('/member/profile/update', user)
      .then(response => cb(response))
      .catch(error => ecb(error))
  }
}
```

So my pattern like that. So i'm using pattern of vuex store

My problem here is I'm still confused to send file data

If I `console.log(user)` in the updateProfile method on modules user, the result is `undefined`

How can I send file data using vuex store?

Comment: i think if we use `vuex` to upload image using `FormData` object it will get an error in payload max size  `'Payload content length greater than maximum allowed: 1048576'`

Answer (score 2):

So if Im using **Vuex** I use **Store.**  If you dont intend to then this answer may not help you. If you are running into issues I would first try storing something like a string because wether its a file or a string, the store functionality should not matter. Once a string is setup , then move to a file (blob , string or arr whatever... ).

Vue has great docs, though things still can be tricky, its good read a lil and have a reference. [Here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getting-started.html)

I use Vuex.Store

```
  import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'

    Vue.use(Vuex)
```

then define your store up like this:

```
     const Store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {


        file:null //any set of state vars can be added her x number of states


      },
    //define your getters
      getters:{
        file: state =>  { return state.file},

      },
    //your mutations to change data
      mutations: {

        SET_FILE(state,payload){
            state.file = payload.value;
        },

      },
//actions to take to commit data 
      actions:{
        //tbd here you can do actions and further manipulate data before committing 
      }
    })

    export default Store;
```

now you can save your file like so

```
Store.commit(
            'SET_FILE',
            {value:yourfile}
        );
```

That saves the state. Whats cool is Vue gives you a store variable you can set in the component by passing to the Vue instance:

```
import Store from ../Globals/Store

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // provide the store using the "store" option.
  // this will inject the store instance to all child components.
  store:Store,
```

Then you can reference by calling this.$store . later you can use this.$store.getters.file to retrieve the file var.  You can stop there (call this.$store.commit) , but note we are not using actions here . You can add actions which add another layer between setting and mutating state.

more on them [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html)

if you want to use actions add something like this where you commit to save the data

```
actions:{

    SAVE_FILE ( {commit} ,payload) {
        commit(
            'SET_FILE',
            {value:payload.value}
        );
    }

  }
```

and you use dispatch to call an action on a Store

so Store.dispatch('SAVE_FILE',{value:file})

hopefully that helps

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487276/how-can-i-send-data-from-parent-to-child-component-by-vuex-store-in-vue-componen

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line:

```
this.updateProfile({formData, reload: true})
```

The `updateProfile` action is expecting to receive an object with `user` and `reload` properties, but you are passing a `formData` property instead of `user`.

Simply pass the `user` property instead:

```
this.updateProfile({ user: formData, reload: true });
```

Comment: If I `console.log(user)` in the updateProfile method, the result like this : https://postimg.org/image/cohduvla3/. I don't find the file sended

Comment: Looks like you're getting the `FormData` that you are passing. Is that not what you are expecting to happen?

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685100/how-to-call-ajax-only-when-show-detail-on-vue-component