# Success upload file via postman but fail on front-end (vue)

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have been success upload file via postman and file has been moved to the folder, but when I try on front-end (vuejs) nothing error but file is not moved,

```
_upload(){

  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('photo', this.photo); // this.photo is base64 data

  this.axios.post('upload_photo', fd, {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  }

  ).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify? Also, I have no idea how `FormData()` works, but why not just make a simple object for the http body? `{photo: this.photo}`

Comment: because it's a file not a text, I have been try use `{photo: this.photo}` but it's not work

Comment: You can pass a base64 string in ajax without problems.

Comment: I use axios in vue not ajax

Comment: ajax stands for **asynchronous javascript and xml**, which axios is. you must be thinking of `$.ajax` which is `jQuery`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading files with VueJS, axios and Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850820/uploading-files-with-vuejs-axios-and-laravel)

Comment: Check your browser's _Network_ console. Can you see the POST request details? How are you uploading the file via Postman; are you also base64-encoding the file there or are you just sending the file as binary? Typically with `FormData` and `multipart/form-data`, you don't need to encode files as you can directly append the file blob

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. First create the variable.

   var photo = ref();
2. bind to input file tag

   <input
   id="photo"
   type="file"
   name="photo"
   hidden
   @change="previewImage"
   @input="photo= $event.target.files[0]"
   />
3. This is the upload function

   const uploadImg = () => {

   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("photo", photo);

   (async () => {
   await axios
   .post(route("editImg"), formData, {
   headers: {
   Accept: "application/json",
   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
   "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
   },
   credentials: "same-origin",
   })
   .then((response) => {
   console.log(response);

   ```
     .catch((e) => {
       console.log("err = ", e);
     });
   ```

   })();
   };